# if I know that $(A\cdot v=\delta \cdot v)$ so what is $(A\cdot v)^k =(\delta\cdot v)k$?

Tags: linear-algebra

$A$ is an $n{\times}n$ matrix , $v$ vector and $\delta$ scalar, $D$ diagonal and $P $ invertible .

1. If I know that $(A \cdot v=\delta \cdot v)$ 
   so what is $(A \cdot v)^k =(\delta \cdot v)^k$?
2. If I know that $$A=PDP^{-1}$$ 
   what is $A^k (k \in N)$ ?

what is $A^T$ ?

Comment: $Av$ and $\delta v$ are $n$-dimensional column vectors, so what do you mean by $(Av)^k$ or $(\delta v)^k$?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! What do you mean with $(A\cdot v)^k$ – the $k$-th power of a vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer the last two questions:

If $A=PDP^{-1}$, then it is easy to check that $\; A^k=PD^kP^{-1}$, and if $D=\operatorname{Diag}(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)$, $\;D^k=\operatorname{Diag}(\lambda_1^k,\dots,\lambda_n^k)$.

As to the transpose, $\;{}^{\mathrm t\negmedspace}A= {}^{\mathrm t\mkern-2mu}P^{-1}{\:}^{\mathrm t\mkern-2mu}D{\:}^{\mathrm t\mkern-2mu}P={}^{\mathrm t\mkern-2mu}P^{-1}{\,}D{\:}^{\mathrm t\mkern-2mu}P$.